# Horizontal scroll view become vertical scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

I want make horizontal scroll view but the result become vertical scroll view. I already tried changing the layout but still couldn't make it horizontal.How to make this card view horizontal?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/retailOutletlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/retailOutletCard"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                cardview:cardElevation="5dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/officelogo" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtStoreName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="PT MATAHARI PUTRA TBK"
                        android:textColor="#004969"
                        android:textSize="22px" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtCompanyAddress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtStoreName"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Jl. Sukanda No 212 Jakarta Barat no 212 jakarta dsadasda"
                        android:textColor="#004969"
                        android:textSize="18px" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Store Manager"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="#004969"
                        android:textSize="22px"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtOwnerStore"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Charles Lee"
                        android:textColor="#004969"
                        android:textSize="22px"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#004969"
                        android:textSize="22px"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="12,Sunset Lane,Coconut Grove Clementi 120999 T:6666 2222 H:6666 2222" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtPostalCode"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="15211"
                        android:textColor="#004969"
                        android:textSize="22px"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for ur help !!

Comment: Update 
  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

to this

  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

Comment: Inside CardView there is a LinearLayout whose orientation is vertical. Can you change it to horizontal ?

Comment: already tried but still cannot

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/retailOutletlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/retailOutletCard"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            cardview:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/officelogo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtStoreName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="PT MATAHARI PUTRA TBK"
                    android:textColor="#004969"
                    android:textSize="22px" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCompanyAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtStoreName"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Jl. Sukanda No 212 Jakarta Barat no 212 jakarta dsadasda"
                    android:textColor="#004969"
                    android:textSize="18px" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Store Manager"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#004969"
                    android:textSize="22px"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtOwnerStore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Charles Lee"
                    android:textColor="#004969"
                    android:textSize="22px"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#004969"
                    android:textSize="22px"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="12,Sunset Lane,Coconut Grove Clementi 120999 T:6666 2222 H:6666 2222" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtPostalCode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="15211"
                    android:textColor="#004969"
                    android:textSize="22px"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```